# How to kill mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

How to kill mercurial repository? Can't find the command to accomplish the task.

Comment: What do yo mean by "killing" the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "kill", but you can remove a repository by deleting the `.hg` directory in your clone. Or just delete your entire clone directory.

Be sure this is *really* what you want to do, though. **There's no undo.**

Comment: I deleted every single file in the repository, but when I try to delete repository folder itself I get the error that folder cannot be deleted because it's in use. And read-only for this folder is checked. I can't uncheck read-only, the flag comes back all the time.

Comment: I understand that there's no undo, I have several clones of this repository, so nothing dangerous is going to happen.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the fact that it's a Mercurial repository. Check that you don't have something else open with your repository directory as its current directory.

Comment: Oops, I really forgot to close a window. Dull mistake. Thank you.